# Qt: make resize event do not move the objects on the scene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I have the following code, which creates a scene and a green rectangle on it (see image below). The problem is, I want the rectangle to stay on its place, when I resize the window, but it moves with it. I don't know where to start: do I need to mess with scene, view, resize event or even rectangle itself? I tried to play with view resize policies, but it had no effect. Thank you in advance!

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene(QRectF(-100, -100, 300, 300));
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    QRectF bonds = scene.itemsBoundingRect();
    view.fitInView(bonds, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    view.centerOn(0, 0);

    QGraphicsRectItem *rectItem =
            scene.addRect(QRectF(-30, -30, 120, 80),
                          QPen(Qt::black),
                          QBrush(Qt::green)
                          );
    rectItem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[App window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDhmC.png)

Comment: Can you explain more what do you need to achieve? do you want the rectangle location to be relative to the window size? i.e. to auto scale and have a relative position to the window or do you mean something else?

Comment: @FadyMohamedOthman For example: if I drag the right bottom corner of the window, the rectangle should stay on its place relative to the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily fix this using `view.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);`, this function will set the alignment of the scene to the top left corner of the `QGraphicsView`.

This is what your code should look like.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene(QRectF(-100, -100, 300, 300));
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    view.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    QGraphicsRectItem *rectItem =
            scene.addRect(QRectF(-30, -30, 120, 80),
                          QPen(Qt::black),
                          QBrush(Qt::green)
                          );
    rectItem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks. I've also read about anchoring mechanism. Can it be used here to reach the same result?

Comment: According to the documentation, you should use alignment since the effect of anchoring is only visible when there are scrollbars, this is the statement from the documentation --

> Note that the effect of this property is noticeable when only a part of the scene is visible (i.e., when there are scroll bars). Otherwise, if the whole scene fits in the view, QGraphicsScene uses the view alignment to position the scene in the view.